# How StoreKit sync non consumable purchases across devices

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

According to Apple documentation, "non consumables are synced across devices by the system", or " non consumables are made available across all of the users's devices", or "StoreKit handles the syncing and restoring process for non consumables". Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any details anywhere about the "syncing" mechanism.
My app saves the purchased status of the non consumable products in UserDefaults which are local only by nature. Using the same app on another device and pressing a Restore button, I don't get any of my previous purchases. **So my questions are :** What Apple means when talking about synchro across devices ? What needs to be added to my app in order to get the purchases synced across devices ?

The code for the **Restore button** is:

```
public func restorePurchases() {    
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

And I have an extension :

```
extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    // Called when a transaction states change
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                complete(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                fail(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                restore(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                break
            case .purchasing:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

And the code for restore is:

```
private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }        
    print("restore... \(productIdentifier)") 
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

And for deliverPurchaseNotificationFor :

```
private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
    guard let identifier = identifier else { return }
    purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var currentStatus = defaults.string(forKey:identifier)
    currentStatus = "Purchased"   // acheté mais pas sauvé
    defaults.set(currentStatus, forKey: identifier)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"), object: identifier)
}
```

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. So when you press restore, what happens? Do any of your `print` statements print? If not, put a breakpoint: is any of your code even running? If so, how far does it get?

Comment: Incidentally, it is wrong to use a string as the `object` in a notification. If you have info to communicate to the recipient, that's what the `userInfo` is for.

Comment: You say "The code for the Restore button is : `public func restorePurchases()`" That makes no sense. What would make a _button_ call this _code_? It is not an `@IBAction`, and Objective-C cannot see it as it is not marked `@objc`. Please show what _really_ happens _when the button is tapped_.

Comment: on the first device, Restore gives me 14 old purchased items (all I purchased in tests). On the second device, where I didn't purchase any yet, Restore gives me nothing.

Comment: I didn't copy the whole texte but it's an action func  // Bouton Restore tappé
    @IBAction func restoreTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        print("entrée dans restoreTapped")
        MyBridgeStoreProducts.store.restorePurchases()
    }

Comment: "Restore gives me 14 old purchased items" Which line of code are we talking about? — And please edit the code in your answer so that you show your _real_ code, not some fake edited version.

Comment: The 14 prints are coming from the line   print("restore... \(productIdentifier)") in the restore function

Comment: Yes, but when "Restore gives me nothing" why is that? Do you mean that it prints nonsense, or do you mean that it prints nothing at all? If it prints nothing, that is presumably because your `transaction.original?` is `nil`. Which makes sense. Just say `let productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier` and away you go.

Comment: The change in the restore func had no effect. The results on the 1st device are :
restoreCompletedTransactions returns 14 transactions. It makes sense. In the restore func, the print is executed 14 times. 
On the 2nd device the results are :
restoreCompletedTransactions doesn’t return any transaction. I have added a print in the paymentQueue func and that print is not executed (where it is executed and giving 14 on the other device. 
It looks like the restored completed transactions are tied to a device and not to an account. Is this due to the Sandbox environment ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely this line:

```
guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }
```

That seems likely to fail. Just write

```
let productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
```